# Prove verification: If $l$ is a limit point then there exists a subsequence that converges to $l$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I want to prove that: If $l$ is a limit point then there exists a subsequence that converges to $l$.
I'm aware of the "standard" proof of this theorem, [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1190635/552998).

But I want to know whether my proof is correct.

---

**My proof:**
Since $l$ is a limit point of $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, we have that $a_n \in (l-\epsilon, l+\epsilon)$ for infinitely many values of $n$. Let $M$ be the set of all such infinitely many values of $n$ $\ldots (1)$

So, $M= \{n\in \mathbb{N}: a_n \in (l-\epsilon, l+\epsilon) \}$ and $M$ is infinite. I will construct a subsequence using this set, now. And here's where I'm "unsure" if my reasoning is correct.

Since $M$ is a non-empty subset of $\mathbb{N}$, there exists a least element in $M$ and let $m_1 = \min M$. Also, as $M \subseteq \mathbb{N}$, $M$ inherits usual ordering of naturals from $\mathbb{N}$ and so we may list down the members of $M$ like: $m_1<m_2<m_3< \ldots$ which means we can always construct a sequence $(m_n)$ which is strictly increasing sequence of naturals and so $(a_{m_n})$ is a subsequence of $(a_n)$

From $(1)$, $|a_n-l|< \epsilon, \forall \, n \in M$ and so $|a_{m_n}-l|<\epsilon , \forall \, n\in \mathbb{N}$ thus $\lim\limits_{n \to ∞} a_{m_n} = l$

---

**Proof 2:**
If $l$ is a limit point then there exists $m_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_{m_1}-l|< \epsilon_0$ and again there exists $m_2 \in \mathbb{N}, m_2>m_1$ such that $|a_{m_2}-l|< \dfrac{\epsilon_0}{2}$ and so on.

Assume for $\dfrac{\epsilon}{k}$ there exists $m_k \in \mathbb{N}, m_k >m_{k-1}$ such that $|a_{m_k}-l|< \dfrac{\epsilon_0}{k}$ then there exists $m_{k+1}>m_k$ such that $|a_{m_{k+1}}-l|<\dfrac{\epsilon_0}{k+1}$ and thus by induction $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}, \exists m_n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_{m_n}-l|<\dfrac{\epsilon_0}{n}$ where $m_1<m_2<\ldots< m_n<\ldots$

And hence a subsequence $(a_{m_n})$ exists.

Now $\forall \epsilon >0,$ if $\epsilon≥\epsilon_0$ then we have that $\forall N \in \mathbb{N}, n≥N \Rightarrow |a_{m_n}-l| <\dfrac{\epsilon_0}{N}≤\epsilon_0 ≤\epsilon$ and if $\epsilon < \epsilon_0$ then $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\dfrac{\epsilon_0}{N} < \epsilon$ hence $\forall n ≥N \Rightarrow |a_{m_n}-l| < \dfrac{\epsilon_0}{N} < \epsilon$

Hence $(a_{m_n}) \to l$

---

Is the reasoning correct or am I just simply nuts? Can someone help me improve it?

Comment: Why is this question downvoted? Please provide a reason so I can improve the question.

Comment: I didn't downvoted, but your reasoning isn't correct. Note that you've taken FOR FIXED $\varepsilon > 0$ a subsequence $(a_{m_n})$ such that $|a_{m_n} - l| < \varepsilon$. It does not implies (since your $\varepsilon > 0$ is fixed) that $a_{m_n} \to l$. If you want to follow this reasoning, I would consider sets $M_{j} := \{ n \in \mathbb N_+ : a_n \in (l - \frac{1}{j}, l + \frac{1}{j})\}$ for any $j \in \mathbb N_+$ and try to choose subseqnece $(a_{n_j})$ such that $a_{n_j} \in M_j$.

Comment: @DominikKutek Very helpful response. Let me scribble around and get back to update this question later.

Comment: @DominikKutek I couldn't do it. I don't understand the part of choosing a subsequence from $M_j$, doesn't it  mean that my subsequence is again not independent of $\epsilon = \dfrac{1}{j}$. Perhaps you can elaborate or answer the question. I honestly don't see how to proceed with your hints.

Comment: I will write an answer, but just to be sure, what is your definition of a limit point?

Comment: @DominikKutek The one that I have used in this question would be good. $l$ is a limit point if $\forall \epsilon >0$, $x_n \in (l-\epsilon, l+ \epsilon)$ for infinitely many values of $n$.

Comment: @DominikKutek To show my efforts, I've also come up with other proof, in case. See my answer (updated). If that's good then I guess, well I'm happy with being able to write just one correct proof.

Comment: The problem with your second proof is similar, you're fixing $\varepsilon > 0$ to early. You firstly need to choose subsequence, then prove that for any $\varepsilon > 0$ you have some $N \in \mathbb N_+$ such that for $j \ge N$ $|a_{n_j} - l| < \varepsilon$. However, as you can see, my answer is really similar to your second proof, but you need to avoid $\varepsilon$ while choosing subsequence (for example by changing every $\varepsilon$ by any positive real number (in my answer it's just $1$)  before "And hence a subsequence $(a_{m_n})$ exists."

Comment: @DominikKutek Thank you for taking your time to help me out. I appreciate your help. But are you not creating subsequence just like mine? You take $\epsilon = \frac{1}{j}$ and I'm just taking $\frac{\epsilon}{j}$. What am I missing? Sorry for the trouble, again.

Comment: I'll change the notation a little in my answer, since you seem to confuse different uses of $\varepsilon$ here. You want to prove something like : there exists a subsequence $(n_j)$ such that for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $N$ such that for any $j > N$ you have $|a_{n_j} - l| < \varepsilon$. Note that you firstly need a subsequence in order to prove it. You can't just prove the latter for your $\varepsilon$ from the beginning. You can take $\frac{\varepsilon}{j}$ while creating subsequence, but then at the end you must use different letter instead of $\varepsilon$ to prove convergence

Comment: Oh wait, are you saying what I've really shown is $$|a_{m_n}-l| < \dfrac{\epsilon_{\text{fixed}}}{N}, \forall n≥N$$ but I need to establish a relation between $\epsilon_{fixed}$ and a general $\epsilon$? Well I think I can do that by saying there exists sufficiently large $N$ for $\epsilon$ however small, $\dfrac{\epsilon_{fixed}}{N}< \epsilon$ that is perhaps, what I intended to write.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant by "my answer is really similar to your second proof", because you've done everything correactly up to the last point. The best way is to avoid using $\varepsilon$ while creating subsequence, or as you've done it above, by distinguishing between $\varepsilon$ from subsequence and $\varepsilon$ from the end (one thing to note is that $\varepsilon$ while creaing subsequence isn't needed at all, since $\frac{1}{j} \to 0$ as $j \to \infty$ and in fact it's only important thing. You can rewrite the same proof by chaning $\frac{1}{j}$ by $c_j$ such that $c_j \to 0$

Comment: @DominikKutek I did it. I fixed the proof. Phew! I can't believe I was confusing myself by using silly notations. Thankfully I got to learn. Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $l \in \mathbb R$ is a limit point of a sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb N_+}$. As you pointed out, it means that for any $\delta > 0$ we have infinitelly many indices $n$ such that $|a_n-l|<\delta$. Now, define for any $j \in \mathbb N_+$ a set $$ M_{j}=\{n \in \mathbb N_+ : |a_n-l| < \frac{1}{j}\}$$ Due to definition of a limit point with $\delta = \frac{1}{j}$ we have at least one element $n_1 \in M_1$. Take it. Now assume (inductivelly) that we've already choosed an increasing sequence $n_1<n_2 < ... < n_k$ for some $k \in \mathbb N_+$. Consider $M_{k+1} \setminus \{1,....,n_k\}$. Since we've thrown away only finitelly many points of $M_{k+1}$ it still (due to assumption of a limit point) have infinitelly many elements in $M_{k+1} \setminus \{1,...,n_k\}$, in particular at least one. Take any $n_{k+1} \in M_{k+1} \setminus\{1,...,n_k\}$. That way, we've formed a subsequence $(a_{n_j})_{j \in \mathbb N_+}$ such that $|a_{n_j} - l| < \frac{1}{j}$ for any $j \in \mathbb N_+$. And it's enough to conclude, since for any $\varepsilon > 0$ we have some $N \in \mathbb N_+$ such that $\frac{1}{N} <\varepsilon$. Then for any $j \ge N$ we will have $|a_{n_j} - l| < \frac{1}{j} < \frac{1}{N} < \varepsilon$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I've upvoted it now for your efforts in trying to educate me. I will accept this answer later once I've finally wrapped my mind around the notations.

Comment: Ah hah, now that I've understood both the proofs, I'm starting to see that they're both actually same. I fixed my second proof. You think it's correct now?

Comment: Yes, it's correct